# Problems while trying to install recaptcha gem on Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundle, bundler, recaptcha

Im trying to install recaptcha on a Rails3 app (Im using Passenger), this is what I did:

1) gem install recaptcha

2) In Gemfile I wrote:
gem 'recaptcha', "0.3.1", :require => 'recaptcha/rails'

3) In the controller where Im going to use it I wrote: 
require 'net/http'

But when I do: bundle install, it says "Killed", and when I try to run the web app, it says: 
Could not find gem 'recaptcha (= 0.3.1, runtime)' in any of the gem sources. (Bundler::GemNotFound)

What should I do? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I started from scratch and follow this: http://thekindofme.wordpress.com/2010/09/25/recaptcha-with-rails-3-without-plugins/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do 'gem install...'; just run 'bundle install' and bundler will fetch everything it needs to satisfy the requirements you specify in your Gemfile.

The 'killed' bit is new to me. Are you running this on a hosted service by any chance? If so, [bundler could be getting killed](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Bundler#Packaging_Your_Gems) if it's using too much memory. That page advises you to use bundle package before deployment.

Comment: Hi, I try everything and nothing works (I think Rails3 has problems with the implementation of plugins made with Ruby 1.8.7), so, I went directly with reCaptcha without plugins http://thekindofme.wordpress.com/2010/09/25/recaptcha-with-rails-3-without-plugins/

Comment: For the record, Ruby 1.8.7 is fine for Rails 3 and gems are not plugins; Rails plugins are an outdated equivalent to gems (more or less).